# How to run a bash script only on directories that have no subdirectories

Tags: command-line, bash, bash-scripting

I would like to process every directory in my parent directory but only on a condition that these directories have no subdirectories in them.

Right now I have a following directory structure:

```
Music
  Band_A
    Record_A1
    Record_A2
  Band_B
    Record_B1
      CD_1
      CD_2
```

And the following script

```
while read -r dir
do
    echo "$dir"
     /Users/rusl/.cliapps/MQA_identifier "$dir" | tee "$dir"/mqa.log
done < <(find . -type d)
```

All it does is checks if every music file in a directory was encoded using MQA and logs its output like this:

```
1   MQA 44.1K   10 - Bury A Friend [MQA 24_44].flac
```

It works and creates the logs I want in directories like Record_A1 and CD_1.

But it also creates a lot of redundant files. For example, it creates a log in Band_A directory, containing output for all files in all subdirectories in Band_A directory or it creates a log in Band_B and then Record_B1, again containing output for all files in respective subdirectories.

So how can I run a script and generate the logs ONLY for those directories that have no nested directories?

EDIT: also I think this script processes every subdirectory as many times as it is nested inside the parent top most directory.
Not that it is critical, but still not efficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basic idea would be to have go through all directories, test if there are subdirectories and if so, run a part of the script.

```
while read -r dir ; do
    subdircount=$(find "$dir" -maxdepth 1 -type d | wc -l)
    if [[ "$subdircount" -eq 1 ]] ; then
        echo "$dir"
        /Users/rusl/.cliapps/MQA_identifier "$dir" | tee "$dir"/mqa.log
    fi
done < <(find . -type d)
```

Comment: `-maxdepth` is not portable. Additionally pathnames with newlines will mislead `wc -l` (but in this case they will mislead `read` as well). Still with GNU `find` and reasonably sane directory tree (like in the OP's example) this will work. +1.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following to find leaf directories:

```
find . -type d -links 2
```

The `-links 2` options looks for files (directories in your case) that have exactly 2 hard links.

A directory has:

- a link to itself
- a link from the parent directory
- a link from each subdirectory

So a directory without subdirectories will have 2 hard links, which is what you want.

Comment: For some filesystems this is not true. E.g. in Btrfs every directory matches `-links 1`. OK, I'm not fully sure if *every* directory *always* matches this but I'm sure it's possible and very common in Btrfs. So you cannot use this approach to solve the OP's problem in general.

Comment: That's a pretty neat trick in itself to find leaf nodes in a directory tree!

Answer (score 2):

This command

```
find . -name . -o -type d -print -prune
```

will generate non-empty output iff there is at least one directory in the current working directory (the core idea came from [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/197775/108618)). You can include it in your shell code as a test. Something like

```sh
if ( cd -- "$dir" && [ -z "$(find . -name . -o -type d -print -prune)" ] ); then
   …
fi
```

where the subshell `( )` prevents `cd` from changing the current working directory of the main script. You could use `find "$dir" …` without `cd` but what if `$dir` expands to something starting with `-`? [Double dash](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/11376/108618) works with `cd`, not with `find`. Well, your main `find` (the one in `<()`) starts in `.`, so one may think all pathnames generated by it will start with `.`. [It seems not all implementations of `find` behave like this](https://superuser.com/q/1480324/432690) though, so it's still good to code defensively.

Alternatively you can build the test into the main `find` command (inside `<()`):

```sh
find . -type d -exec sh -c '
   cd -- "$1" && [ -z "$(find . -name . -o -type d -print -prune)" ]
' find-sh {} \; -print
```

`find-sh` is explained here: [*What is the second sh in `sh -c 'some shell code' sh`?*](https://superuser.com/q/1526229/432690)

Note this approach will run one additional `sh` per directory (with or without subdirectories), this is sub-optimal. I'm introducing it as a small step towards a bigger improvement, because piping to `read` is [not the best way](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/169716/108618) (if you must then it's good you use `-r`; but consider [`IFS=`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/209123/108618) as well).

When piping `find` to `read` like you did, names containing newlines will make the code fail. A good practice is to run everything from within `find`, if possible. In your case it seems possible. The following code is standalone (not inside `<()`).

```sh
find . -type d -exec sh -c '
   cd -- "$1" && [ -z "$(find . -name . -o -type d -print -prune)" ] && do_something_more_with "$1"
' find-sh {} \;
```

The above still runs one `sh` per directory. Now it can be improved by:

```sh
find . -type d -exec sh -c '
   for dir do
      ( cd -- "$dir" && [ -z "$(find . -name . -o -type d -print -prune)" ] ) && do_something_more_with "$dir"
   done
' find-sh {} +
```

Here I used `… && do_something_more_with "$dir"` but you can choose `if … then …` instead.

In your case `do_something_more_with "$dir"` will be

```
{ echo "$dir"; /Users/rusl/.cliapps/MQA_identifier "$dir" | tee "$dir"/mqa.log; }
```

where `{ }` group commands so the preceding `&&` makes the entire group run conditionally.

*Maybe* instead of `do_something_more_with "$dir"` it's better to `do_something_more_with .` in the `$dir` directory. The relevant line will be:

```
( cd -- "$dir" && [ -z "$(find . -name . -o -type d -print -prune)" ] && do_something_more_with . )
```

But it's your decision. You can still `echo "$dir"` (or [better `printf "%s\n" "$dir"`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/65803/108618); note the entire shell code run by `find -exec` is single-quoted, so don't type `printf '%s\n'`).

In case there are extremely many subdirectories in some directory, we really don't need the inner `find` to list them all. To tell whether the output is empty or not it's enough to break after the first line:

```
[ -z "$(find . -name . -o -type d -print -prune | head -n 1)" ]
```

(With `head -c 1` we could break after the first character, but I think `head -c` is not portable.)

So the optimized code may look like this:

```sh
find . -type d -exec sh -c '
   for dir do
      ( cd -- "$dir" && [ -z "$(find . -name . -o -type d -print -prune | head -n 1)" ] ) \
      && { printf "%s\n" "$dir"; /Users/rusl/.cliapps/MQA_identifier "$dir" | tee "$dir"/mqa.log; }
   done
' find-sh {} +
```

---

> also I think this script processes every subdirectory as many times as it is nested inside the parent top most directory. Not that it is critical, but still not efficient.

Unable to reproduce. `find . -type d` prints every directory just once. Maybe `MQA_identifier` works recursively. If it does then it (but not strictly *the script*) will process subdirectories multiple times (with `tee` writing to a file on a different level in the directory tree each time).

Comment: `Maybe MQA_identifier works recursively` - yes, you're absolutely right, it is the app itself that traverses the complete directory tree from every directory. And sorry for not accepting your excellent answer, I really wish I could accept both answers!